# Regression analysis with only categorical variables (both dependent and predictor variables are categorical)

Tags: stata, logistic-regression, categorical-data

I have a dataset with only categorical variables as follows:

```
a.  gender (0=male, 1=female) 
b.  age (18-29, 30-39, 40+)
c.  edu_level (1=primary, 2=secondary, 3=master, 4=don’t_know, 5=none)
d.  residence (1=urban, 2=rural, 3=semi, 4=NA). 
e.  near_hospital (1=yes, 2=no)
f.  takes_vacc (yes, no, don’t_know)
```

I am trying to analyze the impact of the first 5 variables a,b,c,d e  (gender,age, education_level, residence and near_hospital)  on whether the household member will be willing to get the covid19 vaccine (i.e. takes_vacc =1).

The data set would look as follows:

```
| gender   | age      | edu_level | residence | near_hospital | takes_vacc |
| -------- | -------- | --------  --------   --------  --------
| 0        | 18-29    |     1     |      2    |     1         | yes        |
| 0        | 30-39    |     2     |      2    |     1         | yes        |
| 1        | 40+      |     5     |      4    |     2         | no         |
| 1        | 18-29    |     1     |      1    |     1         | yes        |
| 0        | 40+      |     4     |      3    |     1         | yes        |
| 0        | 18-29    |     1     |      3    |     2         | no         |
| 1        | 30-39    |     3     |      2    |     1         | don't_know |
```

What I tried: I used a multinomial logistic regression as follows:

```
mlogit takes_vacc i.gender i.age i.edu_level i.residence i.near_hospital
```

Where i stands for automatically generated dummy variables for all the categories of the respective categorical variables.

The issues and my questions:
I get error as follows: string variables may not be used as factor variables.

1. How do I get rid of that error. Do I need to first encode the variables as “integers”? Please know the data was imported directly from Excel to Stata.
2. Is my model functional or am I missing something? I would like to get any feedback and/or suggestions on how to get this right.

Comment: Use `sencode` to fix this.

Comment: Or `encode`, which would be fine here. #2 as an essentially statistical question is off-topic on SO.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, guys. Encoding the variables was the solution. The rest is about the regression model one chooses as needed.